# IIS7 writing to a share over a network

Tags: c#, iis-7

I am developing an application from windows vista machine. The web application is hosted in IIS. From that application i try to write to a network share on another vista machine but i keep getting the access denied error. On the share i gave everyone, guest, network, anonymous logon full control share and ntfs access. But still access is denied.

However when i start the application from visual studio it perfectly works, from IIS it throws access denied.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a security problem. If you don't run as a user with network privelges, the standard IIS user has no network privileges. Consider this [article](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/QuickDocId.aspx?quickdoc=276).